# How do I use parseJsonBody in Yesod properly?

Tags: json, haskell, yesod, aeson

I'm relatively new to Haskell and I'm currently evaluating Yesod as the foundation of a REST service. I want to be able to communicate using JSON encoded data.

I have a typeclass for storing data using `Persistent`, which is an instance of `ToJSON` and `FromJSON`. However, I'm only able to decode an instance sent to a handler using `Yesod.Core.Json.parseJsonBody_`.

How do I use `parseJsonBody` properly? Do I need to add a type annotation? How can I extract the decoded instance from the result? Please note that I'm not very familiar with Haskell yet.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? It's not clear to me what issue you've run up against.

Comment: try this:
http://www.yesodweb.com/book/json-web-service

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman : I was not able to add a proper type signature for `parseJsonBody` because the types confused me a lot.

@wit : I have read this, but I want to use a simpler function to convert the body to JSON. Besides, I also want to use the goodness of a scaffolded Yesod application. Furthermore -- in my opinion -- the docs are not very newbie-friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out, that I needed to add a proper type signature to make `parseJsonBody` recognize the instance I want to parse:

```
import qualified Data.Aeson as J

postTestR :: Handler Value
postTestR = do
  newTest <- parseJsonBody :: Handler (J.Result Test)
  case newTest of
    J.Error s -> ...
    J.Success a -> ...
```

I understood the problem when I looked at the source of `parseJsonBody_` and how it uses `parseJsonBody` itself.